# Block access to a domain except in one subfolder using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a website, *website.com*, and it also happens to be accessible via *website.ipage.com*. Here's what I need: All requests to *http://website.com* need to be sent to *http://www.website.com*. I have already managed this using the htaccess file below:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^website.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Here's what I can't figure out how to do: All requests to *http://website.ipage.com* must also be sent to *http://www.website.com* **EXCEPT** for *http://website.ipage.com/stats/* (the subfolder */stats/* must still be accessible via website.ipage.com).

I managed to modify the above htaccess file to redirect all requests to *http://website.ipage.com* to *http://www.website.com* by making the following changes:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^(website.com|website.ipage.com) [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Which leaves me with only one question: how do I allow access to *website.ipage.com* **ONLY** if the request is trying to access the */stats/* subfolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add before RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/stats/subfolder [NC]
```